# Why does \ncbar seem to ignore angleB?

Tags: pstricks

I have used `\ncbar` before with success and it worked perfectly however the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}                                                            
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{3cm}
        \rput(-4,0){\rnode{A}{\psframebox[framearc=.3]{A}}}
        \rput(-2,2){\rnode{B}{\psframebox[framearc=.3]{B}}}
        \ncbar[angleA=90,angleB=-90,arrows=->]{A}{B}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Produces me the following:

[image: Output]

The `angleB=-90` is not taken into account.
The `\ncdiag` works just fine. I use TeXmaker on a Linux machine and I compile with LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce it?

Comment: When you run the above code you also get the wrong angle or is it as it is supposed to be?

Comment: I thought so but apart the fact that I remember me using it an example of it can be found here [link to pdf file](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFIQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmirror.ctan.org%2Fgraphics%2Fpstricks%2Fcontrib%2Fpst-node%2Fmore_docs%2Fpsmatrix-docDE.pdf&ei=2Uj8T9rZMeeO0AW1lPWDBw&usg=AFQjCNGa4lYaKDWU167mJvNFcDxzBZ9pnQ&sig2=jjUAUgdL6YkHtnY2JOBZgA)

Comment: @VagelisBebelis: you can get such documents with running `texdoc psmatrix`. No need to load it from the net, it is already present on your computer.

Comment: @Herbert: No need to use `@VagelisBebelis` because you made a comment  for his own question (as well as his answer if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the documentation:

*This node connection consists of a line with arms dropping “down”, at right angles, to
meet two nodes at an angle angleA. Each arm is at least of length armA or armB, but one
may be need to be longer.*

You are looking for `\ncangle[angleA=90,angleB=-90,arrows=->]{A}{B}`

Comment: makes no difference, you can use `angle` or `angleA`. Important is only that `angleB` is not of interest

Comment: Indeed `\ncangle` did the trick. Thanks for your help. Still though I'm sure that `\ncbar` also takes two angles as arguments.

Comment: no, `\ncbar` never used both angles.

Comment: In this example `\ncbar` uses both angles: 

`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-all}                                                            
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,1)(4,-2)
\begin{psmatrix}[emnode=r]
 \psset{arrowscale=2}
 Verbinde {\rnode{A}{KnotenX}} mit
 {\rnode{B}{KnotenY}}!
\end{psmatrix}
\ncbar[nodesep=3pt,angleA=-90,angleB=90,linecolor=
red,arrows=<->,arrowscale=2,
 arm=0.8]{A}{B}
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: set `angleB` to something else, eg 45 and you'll see that nothing happens! `angleB=90` would be a connection from above and not below if the angle would be taken into account.

Comment: and by the way, the environment `psmatrix` in your example makes no sense here

Comment: I copy pasted the code from an obviously bad handbook. Thanks for the clarification I hadn't tried different angles. Also I do not know what the `psmatrix` environment does I'll find out at a later point I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the arms must be parallel then only certain angles that produce parallel arms are valid.

`angle` is the only valid option for `\ncbar` to change the direction. Both `angleA` and `angleB` are not used even though `angle=angleA`.

Comment: In documentation I find \ncbar connecting words using this notation though. It might be problematic because I use psframeboxes?